# BigDecimal CastException in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I am using a bean object to retrieve data from database, called AudienceInfo. AudienceInfo has two attributes:

```
public String messageBody;
public BigDecimal audienceNo;
```

in database messageBody is varchar2 and audienceNo is number.
for fetching data in DAO class, everything is ok and data have been selected.
but when I pass the object (customer) form Dao class to my main class an error happens. here is my code in main class:

```
Iterator<AudienceInfo> iterator = customer.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    BigDecimal com = (customer.get(i).getAudienceno());
    String msgBody = customer.get(i).getMessageBody();
    iterator.next();
    ++i;
}
```

the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to com.htsc.sms.model.bo.AudienceInfo
```

when I use this code in jdbc, everything is ok and I can see the result set but in hibernate I have this problem.

Comment: Side note: why are you using an iteratator _and_ index? That's odd and error prone.

Comment: try BigDecimal com=(customer.get(i).getAudienceno()).getId(); Maybe you still need to have a look at the type of AudiencelInfo's ID

Comment: @Thomas because I need to show all list elements

Comment: Enhanced for loop & toString should solve your issue probably.

Comment: @gefei as I wrote before in oracle database it is number and in bean class it is BigDecimal. I tried your suggestion, nothing happened

Comment: You can show all list elements with just `AudienceInfo ai = iterator.next()` as well - or, as Nayan said, a simpler `for( AudienceInfo ai : customer)` as long as `customer` is `Iterable` (which it seems to be, because of the `iterator()` method).

Comment: Can you please check if your `customer` collection might directly contain a `BigDecimal`? You're using generics here but I have the feeling that they are bypassed in some part of your code resulting in the collection of `AudienceInfo` containing at least `BigDecimal`, which during iteration would be casted to `AudienceInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the answer:
using addScalar in query solved the problem

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select AUDIANCE_NO as audianceno , MSG_BODY as messageBody from SMS_MSG_QUEUE").addScalar("audianceno" , new BigDecimalType()).addScalar("messageBody" , new StringType()).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AudinceInfo.class));
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I down voted this by accident.